# TS использование HTMLElement вместо Node as HTMLElement

Tags: typescript

Дело в том, что TS возвращает node list после метода querySelectorAll. В дальнейшем при переборе в forEach приходится утверждать каждый элемент как HTMLElement для того, что-бы достучаться до таких методов как classList. Выглядит это так: `(element as HTMLElement).previousElementSibling`. А как сделать вот так `element.previousElementSibling`? Не понимаю.

Было:

```
const a = doc.querySelectorAll('.some').forEach((el) => (el as HTMLElement).classList.add('classes'));
```

Хочу чтобы стало:

```
const a = doc.querySelectorAll('.some').forEach((el) => el.classList.add('classes'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll принимает параметр полиморфного типа, что-бы избавиться от проблемы можно написать следующее:

```
const a = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.some')
```

или если нужно использовать в классах:

```
protected readonly elements: NodeListOf<HTMLElement>
```